# selecting a distinct column with alias table not working in postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
 SELECT pl_id,
    distinct ON (store.store_ID),
    in_user_id
    FROM plan1.plan_copy_levl copy1
INNER JOIN plan1._PLAN_STORE store 
    ON copy1.PLAN_ID = store .PLAN_ID;
```

while running this query in postgres server i am getting the below error..How to use the distinct clause..in above code plan 1 is the schema name.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "distinct" LINE 2: distinct ON
>   (store.store_ID),

Comment: `distinct on ()` needs to go at the beginning of the `select` list

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `order by` where the first set of rows should be the ones specified in the `distinct on` clause. Also, the `distinct on` clause should be at start of the selection list.

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct ON (store_ID) store.store_ID, pl_id,
    in_user_id
    FROM plan1.plan_copy_levl copy1
INNER JOIN plan1._PLAN_STORE store 
    ON copy1.PLAN_ID = store .PLAN_ID
    order by store_ID, pl_id;
```

Comment: thanks ..now it throws
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 275: distinct ON (store.store_ID),

Comment: @vigneshramanathan - Updated. Please try using the updated answer?